# How to force closing HTML tags on a new line?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, js-beautify

In VS Code, I use Beautify extensively. But it unnerves me that closing tags always wrap on the same line as "floating" text, or self-closing tags. For instance, before Beautify :

```
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/image.png">
</div>
<div class="wrap">This is just some text
    <strong>but it needs to be emphasized</strong>! And then some...
</div>
```

And after Beautify :

```
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/image.png"> </div>
<div class="wrap">This is just some text
    <strong>but it needs to be emphasized</strong>! And then some... </div>
```

Is there a setting, or another extension that could help get the code closer to what it looks like in the first example, or am I just doing things wrong ?

It doesn't matter much most of the time, other than being a bit ugly to my taste, but yesterday I saw that it actually created problems with Wordpress, I just can't use Beautify anymore, it risks breaking the formatting.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't an option to **force** the end tags to new lines.

One setting that helps is `preserve_newlines`.  Enabling that should keep your tags from getting pulled back to the same line if you have them on their own line.

Version 1.8.1 of js-beautify (the library underlying Beautify for VSCode) improves the behavior in this area, but still doesn't have an option to **force** the end tags to new lines.

Several issues have been filed around this, including [#1468](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/1468) and [#1413](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/1413). PRs are always welcome.

Comment: Do u know how to disable it? I believe the same logic that drives the end tags drives code comments. Both of which are not usable within HTML or PHP files.

Comment: Code comments: not sure, depends on the input.  Unusable in what way?

Comment: comments do not uncomment correctly. They leave adjacent `-->` or double comment. Tags dont work with any type of pasting code. Changing a tag does not update its mate etc. https://res.cloudinary.com/dgu7vsmfd/image/upload/v1536948417/vs-label-wrapping.gif

Comment: @BenRacicot I'm not sure what you're saying. Please file an issue or come to the project Gitter channel.

Answer (score -2):

here is a solution that worked for me.I closed all the input tags with forward slash "/" and all the dives fell to new line.
DONT USE 
USE

Comment: The code the question is asking about doesn't have any `<input>` elements.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

I do not know about that. If you want a similar result to the top bit of code you could use Glitch.Com, Made by the people who made stackoverflow. Glitch hosts your website (website.glitch.com) and has a nice editor, Not to mention project rewind if you want to revert to a previous version.. You have light and Dark theme too.. It automatically closes  tags like this

```
<h1>

</h1>
```

I think it is perfect compared to any other editor, You can have multiple files too.. no download required. Auto saving and perfect for any developer :3

Comment: Great, except for the fact OP specifically said VS code.